# Setting the minimum year AVAILABLE for an Ext.form.DateField

Tags: javascript, date, extjs

I have a basic Ext.form.DateField which needs to have a minimum date.

Easy enough - just set the minValue field to whatever you want the minimum date to be.  For example, to set the minimum allowable date to be the current month and year:

```
var myDateField = new Ext.form.DateField({ 
            fieldLabel: 'Date',
            value: new Date(),              
            columnWidth: 0.15,
            padding: 5,
            format: 'n/Y', 
            plugins: 'monthPickerPlugin',
            hidden: false,
            minValue: new Date()
        });
```

If the user enters a date from the past, the form displays an error message that states 'The date in this field must be equal to or after ...' and the bound component.

However, what I really need is for the user to not even be able to SELECT an earlier year from the picker in the first place.

Basically, when the calendar comes up, I need for it to only display years 2015 and later - for the following, the years 2011, 2012, 2013, and 2014 should not even appear in the calendar.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that is doable.

You can disable dates using either the **minValue** or **disabledDates** configs, but they will still appear in the list.

However, once a user selects the month they are disabled, see below screenshot and sample:

[disabled dates in calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Et9T.png)

```
ie.
```

```js
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Dates',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'From',
        name: 'from_date',
        minValue:"01/01/2015",
        disabledDatesText:"Date not available.",
        maxValue: new Date()  // limited to the current date or prior
    }]
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/ext-all.js"></script>
```